# Why can't I proxy SSL connections in Charles under Linux (ubuntu)?

Tags: java, ssl, curl

I want to proxy some API requests  over SSL from a PHP application using Charles Proxy which should allow me to view unencrytped requests. I've done this on Windows before but on Linux, I'm seeing the following error in Charles:

SSL: java.security.ProviderException: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception:CKR_DOMAIN_PARAMS_INVALID

The requests are sent to a SOAP webservice from a PHP web app using CURL. I am setting the relevant CURL Options in PHP and have tried setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false.

I also tried this - http://shickys.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/addressing-openjdk-bug-with-ssl-on.html

Comment: What Charles version? I upgraded to 3.7 and this broke for me too

Comment: Also Charles 3.7, though I think it might be an underlying Java problem. As I'm running Ubuntu in a VM, I am getting around it by routing PHP traffic through Charles running on the Windows 7 host